# USB to Serial, Port Name Changing Unexpectedly

Tags: serial-port, usb, converters, allocation, ports

I've got a Windows 7 Pro 64 PC with a FTDI based 4 port USB to RS232 converter.  I've been having periodic problems with the port name (port numbers) changing.  Most recently this occurred when the USB cable got accidently yanked out of the PC while connected to one device.  The original port numbers were 3, 4, 5, 6.  When I plugged the cable back in the ports were reallocated as 7, 8, 9, 10.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent Windows from reassigning the port names / numbers?

Comment: It is not Windows that assigns the port numbers, it is the driver.  The FTDI driver is notorious for not dealing with surprise removal well.  In general a problem with USB emulators.  Nothing you can do about it but glue the connector or go shopping for another one.

Comment: I went into device manager and reassigned ports 7, 8, 9, 10 back to 3, 4, 5, 6 and did several forced disconnects and didn't see the problem again.